# Deploying .jar file: Why can't I load icon files?

Tags: java, deployment, resources, jar

I'm exporting a simple java project that includes two directories; src and Icons. Icons is a directory that contains three .png files.

I'm exporting to an executable .jar file using File -> Export. The export works properly and the .jar file contains the Icon directory. But I can't get the correct path for the .png files when the project is deployed. During the development I'm using the following path:

> Icons/picture.png

and it works as long as I run from within the Eclipse IDE.
How do I get the correct path for the icons?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is looking for the image outside of the .jar file. Try the [URL constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.net.URL)) of `ImageIcon` instead.

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icons/picture.png"));
```

See [`Class.getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 4):

mmyers is correct, but be aware that `getClass().getResource()` will load resources *relative to the package where the class is defined*. I suspect your icons are packaged at the root of the jar file and not relative to the class itself. To get resources from the root of the classpath, try:
    `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Icons/picture.png")`